# vue pass custom component as a property to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I haven't quite seen other questions which try to answer what I'm doing and I'm not sure if it's just that I'm not searching for the correct verbage so I'll explain what's going on.

I'm trying to develop an interface where the user can drag or input an image with vue. I also have a component which I've made called `Card` which is a bit of vue and bulma for a card-like object. The `Card` component has two `props`, `title` and `content`. Very straight forward to use when what you want to fill in the `title` and `content` properties are pre-loaded text or image data.

However, what I want to do is place another **vue component** inside the `Card` (a `PictureInput` component from `vue-picture-input` on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-picture-input)). I'm trying to do this by passing it as the `content` prop. I have read the vue documentation on [reactive props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) and [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), but neither really talk about this use case.

Code:

**Card.vue:**

```html
    <template>
      <div class="card is-size-7-mobile is-fluid">
        <div class="card-header">
          <a class="card-header-title">
            <span class="is-info">{{this.title}}</span>
          </a>
          <span v-if="this.isExpanable">
            <a class="card-header-icon card-toggle">
              <span class="icon" @click="arrowClick">
                <span v-if="!this.open">
                  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'angle-down']"></font-awesome-icon>
                </span>
                <span v-else>
                  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'angle-up']"></font-awesome-icon>
                </span>
              </span>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
          <slide-up-down :active="this.open" :duration="400" v-if="this.isExpanable">
            <div v-if="this.open" class="card-content is-size-7-mobile">
              <div class="content">{{this.content}}</div>
            </div>
          </slide-up-down>
          <div v-else>
            <div class="content">{{this.content}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          open: false
        };
      },
      props: {
        title: "",
        content: null,
        isExpanable: false
      },
      methods: {
        arrowClick(event) {
          this.open = !this.open;
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    .card {
      border-radius: 1em;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      border-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .card-header {
      box-shadow: transparent;
    }
    </style>
```

**ImageInput.vue:**

```html
    <template>
    <div class="content">
        <Card :title="makeCardTitle()" :content="makeCardContent()"/>
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input';
    import Card from './Card';
    import Vue from 'vue';
    
    export default {
        name: 'ImageInput',
        components: {
            PictureInput,
            Card
        },
        props: {
            idx:{
                type:Number,
                default: 0
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pictureComponent: "PictureInput"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            makeCardTitle: function(){
                return "page ".concat(String(this.idx))
            },
            makeCardContent: function(){
                var PictureInputClass = Vue.extend(PictureInput);
                var pictureInputInstance = new PictureInputClass();
                return pictureInputInstance
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

As you can see with the `ImageInput.vue` code I've tried to dynamically construct the `PictureInput` object and pass it as the prop `content` to `Card` but it doesn't work, I get two errors one being a "Cyclic object value" in `Card` and the other being that the `PictureInputClass` object doesn't have a `toJSON` method, which I'm guessing some part of the vue framework expects. I've also tried just doing:
`<Card :title="makeCardTitle()" :content="PictureInput"/>`, but I end up getting errors about how the `PictureInput` isn't defined but is referenced during render. Maybe I can change `content` to a named `<slot></slot>` but I'm not sure if that's what I want either.

The reason I'm going through all of this is that I really appreciate how Vue is designed to allow components to be re-used and re-integrated into each other when creating an interface. I obviously could just take (most of) the template from `Card` and re-configure it for this case but I wanted to see if there was an easier way to get the `PictureInput` component to be a child of the `Card` component.

Comment: Slots seem more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use slots to place the PictureInput component into the Card component. I removed some HTML for a simplified example.

Card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card is-size-7-mobile is-fluid">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-header-title">

                <!-- Don't need to use "this" keyword inside the template,
                it is implied that the context is already "this" -->
                <span class="is-info" @click="isExpanable = !isExpanable">{{title}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div v-if='isExpanable'>
            <slot/> <!-- Slot where the <PictureInput/> will be inserted -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isExpanable: false, // internal state to manage the open/close toggle
    }
  },
  props: {
    title: String, // Define the data type
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.card {
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
.card-header {
  box-shadow: transparent;
}
</style>
```

ImageInput.vue

```
<template>
<div class="content">
    <Card :title="makeCardTitle">
        <PictureInput/>
    </Card>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input';
import Card from './Card';

export default {
    name: 'ImageInput',
    components: {
        PictureInput,
        Card
    },
    props: {
        idx:{
            type:Number,
            default: 0
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // Should be a computed property since we are creating data from internal data "idx"
        makeCardTitle: function(){
            return "page ".concat(String(this.idx));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Hopefully this guides you in the right direction. Also, you shouldn't have to instantiate  with Vue.extend(PictureInput). Usually, all you need to do is add it to the components option key.